# SQL Self Join to separate users and agents

Tags: sql, self-join

I am trying to learn sql and was hoping to get assistance on a question I came across.

I have a table like below.

```
ticke no, created,  sender
1,  9:00 AM,    user
1,  9:30 AM,    agent
1,  10:00 AM,   user
1   5:00 PM agent
2   11:00 AM    user
2,  1:00 PM,    user
2,  3:00 PM,    agent
3,  2:00 PM,    agent
3,  2:30 PM,    user
3,  9:00 PM,    agent
3,  10:00 PM,   user
4,  11:00 PM,   agent
```

I need to separate the Sender field into two columns one with only user populated and the other with only agent populated. To get something like this

```
ticke no, created,  User, Agent
1,  9:00 AM,    user, NULL
1,  9:30 AM,    NULL, agent
1,  10:00 AM,   user, NULL
1   5:00 PM,    NULL, agent
2   11:00 AM    user, NULL
2,  1:00 PM,    user, NULL
2,  3:00 PM,    NULL, agent
3,  2:00 PM,    NULL, agent
3,  2:30 PM,    user, NULL
3,  9:00 PM,    NULL, agent
3,  10:00 PM,   user, NULL
4,  11:00 PM,   NULL, agent
```

Below is my closest attempt. I am quite lost since I am a beginner.

```
Select TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.[Ticket Number], TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.[Created     At] as UserTime, TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.Sender as UserSender,
(
    select TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.Sender as AgentSender
    from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc
    where TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.Sender = 'agent'
)
from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc
where TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.Sender = 'user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `case` statement:

```
Select sd.[Ticket Number], sd.[Created     At] as UserTime, 
       (case when sender = 'user' then sender end) as sender,
       (case when sender = 'agent' then sender end) as agent
from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc sd
where sd.Sender = 'user';
```